# simplelog::CombinedLogger panicking at runtime

Tags: rust

I'm using the log and simplelog crates. Previously this code worked:

```
use simplelog::*;

CombinedLogger::init(
    vec![
        TermLogger::new(LevelFilter::Warn, Config::default()).unwrap(),
        WriteLogger::new(LevelFilter::Info, Config::default(), File::create("main.log").unwrap()),
    ]
).unwrap();
```

But now it throws this error at runtime:

```
thread 'main' panicked at 'called `Option::unwrap()` on a `None` value', /checkout/src/libcore/option.rs:335:21
stack backtrace:
```

Cargo.toml dependencies:

```
log = "0.4.1"
simplelog = "0.5.0"
```

Comment: The error message is straightforward: you got a `Option::None` from your function. Find why by reading your backtrace.

Comment: The three places that can spawn an unwrappable value are `CombinedLogger::init`, `TermLogger::new`, and `File::create`. Of those three, the only one that returns an `Option` is `TermLogger::new`; the rest return `Result`s. Something is wrong with your `TermLogger::new` arguments, I'd assume.

Comment: OP, please add the backtrace in your question!

Comment: Ditto what @Boiethios said. While in this case it was trivial to discover where (we *think*) the error came from, in the future a backtrace will make it clearer whether the error is from the posted code or something less obvious.

Answer (score 2):

The documentation of [`TermLogger::new`](https://docs.rs/simplelog/0.4.2/simplelog/struct.TermLogger.html#method.new) is not good, because it does not explain why it returns an `Option`.

I read [the code](https://github.com/Drakulix/simplelog.rs/blob/master/src/loggers/termlog.rs#L105): the function can fail because of [`term::stdout()`](https://stebalien.github.io/doc/term/term/fn.stdout.html) or [`term::stderr()`](https://stebalien.github.io/doc/term/term/fn.stderr.html). Reading the documentation, your code fails because *a terminal couldn't be opened*.

Comment: I was in the middle of constructing a response in this vein; couldn't it fail due to `term::stderr()` as well?

Comment: @BHustus Sure, I will add it.

Comment: I believe it's worth mentioning this issue at [`simplelog`'s repository](https://github.com/Drakulix/simplelog.rs).